# Help me to understand this schematic

Tags: bjt

I found 220V AC to 12V DC - 30A power supply schematic:

[image]

[image]

My question is, where Ib1 current goes (where base pin is connected)?

Edit:

Here is one more schematic with same strange base pin connection:

[image]

Edit:

Is it same as:

[image]

?

Comment: This is a common representation of transistors that share a common base. It saves space, due to the somewhat cumbersome symbol. Do you need explanation of how the *circuit* functions?

Comment: Yes, I want explanation...

Comment: Yes you understand how it is connected.

Comment: A more advanced method of a `pass transistor` regulator setup. It allows a simple voltage regulator to use a beefier external power transistor instead of its weaker internal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no load resistance, no current flows out of the 7812. No current flows in, either, therefore the voltage drop across `R7` is almost zero. The bases of all the transistors are held at the same voltage as their collectors, so they do not conduct.

As current is drawn by the load, the current out of - and into - the 7812 increases. This causes a voltage to be dropped across `R7`. As the load current increases (to around 7mA in this case), the voltage across `R7` reaches 0.7V, and so the transistors begin to turn on and conduct. Their collectors are *always* held at the output voltage of the regulator.

As the transistors turn on, they start to 'divert' the current drawn by the load away from the regulator. The 7812 does not have to be able to conduct much current at all, as the larger the drop across `R7` the harder the transistors are turned on. Eventually an equilibrium is reached, usually with the 7812 only making up around 5% of the current supply. However, this figure depends on values of `R1-6` and their ratio to the value of `R7`, plus the characteristics of the particular transistors.

Comment: The Idea comes from pre internet Ham Radio 1976 or earlier .The idea was that the reg fed a current mirror of reasonably fixed gain so the shutdown features of the IC would be amplified and preserved giving something idiot proof at the expense of one more VBE of voltage waste .The geniuses on the internet knew it all and removed that feature and placed a 470microfarad cap in to stress the PSU out everytime its switched on for good measure .

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell by the schematic supplied, but those base pins are in parallel. The current flows into each emitter, and out of both the base and collector. From the base, the current flows into LM7812C. From the collector, the current flows through that 30A fuse to the load.

Comment: You mean 30A *fuse*...

Comment: Oh, yes. You're right. I'll fix that...